# How to convert a bunch of videos using avconvert on MacBook?

Tags: video, encoding, video-editing

I have to convert a lot of videos and save the metadata. The only way I found is to create the command for every video and paste it into Terminal. If I select all the files in the folder and convert them, the metadata will lost.

How can I do this faster?